# Improve Performance On Protected Routes

Tags: performance, jwt, sveltekit, 1password, passage-1password

I'm building a SvelteKit, using Passage by 1Password for (auth [docs](https://docs.passage.id/)).

On a specific route and all its subroutes, I need to authenticate and ensure that the user is logged in. According to my profiler, this takes 1 second. This is far too slow for the ideal user.

Passage suggests a function - I've instead investigated a little bit and gone deeper, and I finally am using the `jose.jwtVerify` function. This takes about the same time.

How can I improve this? Is there any way to "cache" the fact that the user is logged in? How do other frameworks make this protection fast?

---

Some tips: [Here](https://github.com/passageidentity/passage-node/blob/e9bf6ca5dcf77922ecbe18102590ef263a6e68e2/src/classes/Passage.ts#L2) is the GH code. As you an see, the key for `jwtVerify` is this:

```js
createRemoteJWKSet(new URL(`https://auth.passage.id/v1/apps/${this.appID}/.well-known/jwks.json`), {
    cacheMaxAge: 1000 * 60 * 60 * 24, // 24 hours
});
```

Perhaps it's *this contact with an API* that slows down this process. Anyway, is there anyway to improve on this?

---

If anybody knows Passage - is it possible for me to download/cache that JWK file? I'm guessing it changes, right? Or does `cacheMaxAge` cache it after all - *or* does Svelte SSR on serverless Vercel nullify this caching?